# Is my understanding of how Promises resolve correct?

Tags: javascript

Can I confirm if my understanding of the code below is roughly correct?

```js
function fetchDog(){
  k = fetch("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random") 
  console.log(k);
};

fetchDog();
```

`k` is displayed on the console as a `Promise` object. Because the console is live, this promise does resolve to fulfilled.

```js
function fetchDog(){
  fetch("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random") 
  .then(response => console.log(response)) 
};

fetchDog();
```

The fulfilled promise resolves to a response object. It ceases being a `Promise` object because it's resolved to something else entirely.

Comment: Rephrase you question.

Comment: `k` is still the `Promise` object in both pieces of code. `.then()` is essentially how you register a callback function -- the `Promise` handler calls whatever function you pass into `.then()` with the result of the Promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, a resolved promise is **still** a promise. The value doesn't magically get overwritten. What `.then` is doing is it's essentially adding a function as a listener and saying, once the promise resolves, run this function with the value that the promise is resolved with. So, inside the function, `response` is not the promise, but the contents of the promise. The actual promise still lives on. Consider this code:

```js
const x = Promise.resolve("hello"); // generate a promise that immediately resolves to "hello"
x.then(v => console.log(v));
x.then(v => console.log(v));
// "hello" is logged twice
```

Comment: Ok so the 'promise lives on' but it's just `.then` has captured the 'value' of the promise (when it's fulfilled) as its argument?

Comment: That's essentially what it does.

Answer (score 3):

No.

A promise will always be a promise. It's state may change from pending to resolved, but nothing about promises causes variables referencing them to mutate to reference their resolved value.

To get the resolved value you need to use `then()` or `await`.